# How to indicate resource deletions in a FHIR response without sending the full resource history?

Tags: hl7-fhir

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76055373) about subscription error recovery without the $events operation. The premise of that question is that in a sufficiently busy system, the cost of indefinitely accumulating events for failed subscriptions would be too high, so there should be another way to recover from errors - a way that does not rely on such events being stored.

Instead, it should provide a list of changes compared to the state of the system at an earlier point in time (specified by the client based on the last successfully delivered notification). This list of changes would include resource creation, updates and deletions, but only the latest state of each resource (no intermediate versions).

However, it is unclear what Bundle type would be feasible for returning such a set of changes:

- Items in bundles of type `searchset` must always include a resource and can not include a `request.method`, so it is not possible to indicate deleted resources.
- Bundles of type `history` can include deletions but their items should not be resources but *versions* of resources, so omitting intermediate versions and putting versionless resources (reflecting their latest states) in them would probably not be FHIR-compliant.
- Bundles of types `subscription-notification`, `transaction` and `batch` are for entirely different purposes, so their usage would be confusing and not FHIR-compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the use cases I have heard of in the past actually want the intermediate versions because some of those state transitions might be meaningful. The system-level or type-level _history method is intended for exactly this case - retrieving all changes since a given timestamp, in the form of a history bundle (likely with a lot of pagination, considering how many changes could have accumulated).

However, if the intermediate resources are omitted from the result set by some custom operation, a history bundle containing only the most recent versions is only a little bit different from a searchset. I don't see having "versionless" resources as significantly different - is there a specific data element that would be problematic? A custom operation returning a history bundle does not create a conformance problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please give me an example where the intermediate versions could be relevant?

Comment: Suppose I have a ServiceRequest that has gone from status=draft at the last snapshot, then to status=active and then later to status=completed. A downstream system might want to track how long it was in each of those states - if the intermediate versions are omitted it could only tell how long it took to go from draft to completed. Or there could be a system that wants to trigger some processing every time a ServiceRequest goes into the active state - in that case it would never trigger on this resource.